# Python: Stopping miniDOM from expanding escape sequences

Tags: python, xml, minidom

When xml.dom.minidom parses a piece of xml, it automagically converts escape characters for greater than and less than into their visual representation. For example:

```
>>> import xml.dom.minidom  
>>> s = "<example>4 &lt; 5</example>"
>>> x = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(s)
>>> x.firstChild.firstChild.data
u'4 < 5'
```

Does anyone know how to stop minidom from doing this?

Comment: The behavior is correct - the conversion of entities into their associated CDATA is an integral part of "parsing" XML.

Comment: i suppose that makes sense... but is there no way to stop this particular piece of "parsing"?

Comment: Just curious: Why do you ever want to do that? Most likely, you're about to write buggy software.

Comment: Because I'm doing a lot of the manipulation of the text at the string level, and it's really annoying to have lesser than and greater than in there, because it confuses functions that do things like strip tags. I don't see how using &lt; and &gt; will make me more likely to write buggy software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import xml.dom.minidom
>>> s = "<example>4 &lt; 5</example>"
>>> x = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(s)
>>> x.firstChild.firstChild.toxml()
u'4 &lt; 5'
```